# Spliting multiple variable C++ functions for quadrature integration

Tags: c++, integration

I want to numerically integrate with `boost::math::quadrature::trapezoidal(g, a, b, 1e-6);` Here I'm integrating the function g(x). The problem is that I have to perform a double integral. Furthermore, I have 4 variables in the function I want to integrate. 2 of them I pass while integrating (m,n) and the other 2 are the integration variables (r,z). This is the integral I want to compute:

$$
\int_0^b\int_0^af(r,z)\sin{(\frac{n\pi}{a}z)}J_0(\frac{\alpha_{0,m}}{b}r)dzdr
$$

I saw this example [Performing 2d numerical integration with Boost Cpp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35106/performing-2d-numerical-integration-with-boost-cpp) and notices that he uses lambda functions to split the main integrand in 2. so far I have managed this

```
double integrate(int m, int n)
{ 
  auto f1 = [](double r, double z, int m, int n) { return integrand(r,z,m,n); };
  auto f = [&](double r, m) {
         auto g = [&](double z, n) {
            return f1(r, z);
              };
         //return gauss_kronrod<double, 61>::integrate(g, 0, a, 5);
         return boost::math::quadrature::trapezoidal(g, 0, a, 1e-6);
       };
  double error;
  //double Q = gauss_kronrod<double, 15>::integrate(f, 0, b, 5, 1e-9, &error);
  double Q =  boost::math::quadrature::trapezoidal(f, 0, b, 1e-6);
  //std::cout << Q << ", error estimated at " << error <<std::endl;
  return Q;
}
```

The implementation of the function $f(r,z)$ and the rest of the integral is the following

```
double initial(double r, double z, int m, int n)
{
return std::sin(M_PI*n*z/a)*std::cyl_bessel_j(0, boost::math::cyl_bessel_j_zero(0,m)*r/b);
}
double integrand(double r,double z,int n,int m)
{
  return initial(r,z,m,n)*std::sin(M_PI*n*z/a)*std::cyl_bessel_j(0, boost::math::cyl_bessel_j_zero(0,m)*r/b);
}
```

Normally the Initial won't need them and n variables but in this case, I need to make some tests.

The problem is that I really don't understand how to split my function like in the example for my problem and perform the integration because boost only accepts 1 variable functions.

Please help

Comment: To see what's happening, create separate functions for all the lambdas.  Also, you are missing m and n when you return f1 from the lambda function g.

Comment: Hi, the thing is that boost only accepts 1 variable function, so g and f must be only 1 varialbe, don't know what to do with m and n.

Comment: This looks like a programming question on how to pass parameters to lambdas, so it seems off-topic here.

Comment: @CarlosAndrésdelValle:  You don't have to call the boost function with two arguments.  Just pre-multiply the argument with m or n before you send it to boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is, as usual, to integrate in two steps. For this you first solve the inner integral and make another one-dimensional function out of it, which you then pass again to the integrator.

The lambda is used whenever you want to cut down a multi-parameter function to a single-parameter function. In this case, you put all that is not the integrated variable in the lambda capture.

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
double integrand(double r,double z, int m,int n, double a, double b)
{
   //this is the function you want to integrate
}

double integrate(int m, int n)
{
    double a=1.0;
    double b=1.0;

    auto inner_integral = [m,n,a,b](double z)
    {
        auto f = [z,m,n,a,b](double r) { return integrand(r,z,m,n,a,b);} 
        return trapezoidal(f,0,a);
    }
    return trapezoidal(inner_integral,0,b);
};
```

You probably don't need to write out the lambda capture, i.e. a reference capture with `&` will likely work as well (`auto inner_integral = [&](double z){...}`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question, the compiler is screaming about missing ; or , before the last return, and is saying that the function doesn't have a return statement. How could I solve that? What's that ; in the last }?

Comment: Yes, and it's right. Aftet the final lambda bracket, before return, must be a ";".